# Adding an image to laravel-excel header

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I'm making an excel export using the Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel version 3.1. I am trying to add an image to the header of every page but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried following the phpspreadsheet documentation for inserting image, but that doesn't seem to work.

````
$drawing->setName('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
$drawing->setPath('./images/PhpSpreadsheet_logo.png');
$drawing->setHeight(36);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->addImage($drawing, \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooter::IMAGE_HEADER_LEFT);```
````

Comment: Try using the absolute path to the image instead of a relative path.

Comment: Thanks but I already Tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @SaitamaKalbo did you ever get this working? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```js
$filename = 'File Name';

Excel::create($filename, function($excel){

   $excel->sheet('sheet name', function($sheet){
        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing;
        $objDrawing->setPath(public_path('img/headerKop.png')); //your image path
        $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A2');
        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
   });

})->export('xls');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
$drawing = new Drawing();
$drawing->setName('Logo');
$drawing->setDescription('This is my logo');
$drawing->setPath(public_path('/images/PhpSpreadsheet_logo.png'));
$drawing->setHeight(36);
$drawing->setCoordinates('A1');
```